# Mongo Connection To Private EC2 Instance Failed

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

I have two instances in AWS on separate subnets in same VPC. One of them is private while other is public. I have my node application setup in public instance. The private instance is accessible from public instance only as they are in same VPC. I tried to connect to mongodb of private instance from public instance using the following command:

```
sudo ./mongo <private ip>:27017 -u <username> -p <password> --authenticationDatabase myDatabase
```

Below is my mongodb configuration:

```
fork = true
bind_ip = 0.0.0.0
port = 27017
quiet = true
dbpath = /var/lib/mongodb
logpath = /var/log/mongodb/mongo.log
logappend = true
journal = true
```

But this command timeouts after some time and gives error as below:

```
2016-01-18T12:17:57.513+0000 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't connect to server <my private ip>:27017, connection attempt failed :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:226:14
@(connect):1:6

exception: connect failed
```

I want to use this mongo connection from the node js application in the public instance. What can be the reason the instance is not able to connect from the public instance?

Comment: By defalt, Mongodb only allows connections from localhost

Comment: I have added my mongo config in edits. I believe bind_ip = 0.0.0.0 allows all.

Comment: Does the Security Group of the MongoDB instance(s) allow inbound port 27017 from the Security Group of the Node,js instance(s)?

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12523460/how-to-open-mongo-port-in-amazon-aws-vpc-private-subnet?rq=1.

Comment: what is your OS type, ubuntu or amazon linux?

Comment: @rummykhan The OS type is amazon linux

Comment: @jarmod I think the security group does not have that. I have followed a video to setup private and public instances. I have also setup a NAT instance. What changes do I have to make?

Comment: can you ping that from public instance, if you can then it shows that there is only port issue otherwise its Okay and you have configured it correctly..

Comment: I tried ping from public to private instance. It is failing :O.
`PING <private ip> (<private ip>) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- <private ip> ping statistics ---
75 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 75513ms`

Comment: Adding exception to security group for port  27017 and my public instance ip made it work. Thanks @jarmod

Comment: @SagarGopale Glad it's working. I have added that advice as an answer so you can mark the question as answered to help future readers.

Comment: @rummykhan Note that ping can fail for a number of reasons, for example if you have not allowed inbound ICMP in the MongoDB security group rules or if there is actually no process running on the MongoDB instance that responds to ICMP ping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Security Group of the MongoDB instance(s) needs to allow inbound port 27017 from the Security Group of the Node.js instance(s).

You can also allow this communication from Node.js to MongoDB using the IP addresses of the source Node.js instance(s), but it's much better to simply allow ingress from their security group. That helps when Auto Scaling adds new instances, for example, or if your Node.js servers are terminated and then restarted with new IP addresses.